# Energy States In Conway's Game Of Life

Tags: matrices, algorithms

Conway's game of life is a very interesting simulation, with all of the cells occupying a specific "mode" - dead or alive. In the game, there are infinitely many simulations that you can run, with the majority of them just dying. However, what I am interested in is how the simulations (The ones where the population does not just die out) always find the best possible Energy state. Now, what I mean by "energy state" is a specific number that describes how stable a simulation is. Lets say the lower the better. I will call this the simulation's $\ E$ state. This, however, is an abstract concept. You can't exactly measure it (not that I doubt someone could create a method for estimating $\ E $ values). Instead, you can say that it is a measure of how *close* the simulation is to becoming stable. Now what do I mean by "stable"? Allow me to elaborate:

For a simulation to be stable, it must fit the following:

- No "organisms" can move about, or die.
- The population of "cells" cannot change.

I will also be using matrices to represent my simulations. Here is an example of a stable "organism" (1 means a living cell, 0 means a dead cell):
$$\ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
This "organism" is stable because if we look at the rules for Conway's Game Of Life, we will see that no cells around the "organism" can be born, and none can die since they all have 2 neighbours. This "organism" also fits our stable criteria - the population of cells never changes, and  the "organism" does not move or die. This makes it perfectly stable with an $\ E$ value of exactly $\\ 0$. This means it has got the lowest possible energy states. However, what I have noticed in the game is that no matter what starting "seed organism" I choose (I do fully appreciate that some creatures do never enter an energy state of $\ 0$), they always, after an arbitrary number of generations, settle down to the lowest possible energy state, $\ E = 0$. This brings me to my question - how many "organisms" are there that do this, and why does this always happen in these creatures?

Comment: One important part of the fascination of this game is that it is in general undecidable. We cannot predict in general, whether a given cell will eventually die, unless we use a finite board.